# In Windows Azure, does the CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock method use TCP or UDP as the transport protocol?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating an application to optimize the blob upload using the Azure SDK.

I wanted to know if the PutBlock method uses TCP or UDP as its underlying transport protocol?

And whichever it uses, can I write a custom function which does the blob upload operation using my own protocol? Because that is what I plan on doing to optimize my use case.

EDIT 1:
Thanks Guillaume,
Although I am unsure what you mean by that, even if I do add a proxy worker role, wouldn't it eventually be using the HTTP/TCP protocol of the REST API to do the job. In that case, wouldn't my protocol be just another overhead that slows stuff down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Azure Storage Blobs are managed through a [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179355.aspx) (http or https) so **it's TCP**. You don't have any control on the Azure Blob Storage protocol, you can only choose between http or https.

If you want to upload to Azure with your own protocol, you'll have to add a 'proxy' worker role (or another VM instance, see David's comment) that exposes an endpoint with your protocol then uploads data to the blob using the regular REST blob endpoint. As your worker and storage account are in the same data center that shouldn't be a bottleneck.

---

To answer the second part of your question, yes there is more overhead but it might not slow stuff down.
Let's say the Blob Protocol overhead is 10% and your own protocol has 5% overhead. Let's say the connection between client and Azure is 128kbps and 1Gbps Inside Azure (totally random numbers only to demonstrate the potential result).

- Client to Blob ==> 10Mb with 10% overhead at 128kbps => 00:11:27
- Client to Proxy => 10Mb with 5% overhead at 128kbps ==> 00:10:56
- Proxy to Blob ==> 10Mb with 10% overhead at 1Gbps ==> 00:00:00
  (really fast!)

Client to Proxy + Proxy to Blob = 10min 56sec, that's faster ;)

Now do your own [download time calculations](http://www.numion.com/calculators/time.html) with measured bandwidth and overhead (and you should also think about latency,...).

Comment: Good answer, but *Worker Role* is a specific type of VM instance, and is unrelated to the question. Proxy code can live in many places (mobile service, virtual machine, web role, worker role, web site...).

Answer (score 0):

In [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for HTTP/1.1 it is written that HTTP can be implemented on top of any reliable protocol. But UDP is not reliable therefore I do not expect reasonable implementation of HTTP over UDP.

> HTTP communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections. The
> default port is TCP 80 [19], but other ports can be used. This does
> not preclude HTTP from being implemented on top of any other protocol
> on the Internet, or on other networks. HTTP only presumes a reliable
> transport; any protocol that provides such guarantees can be used;

You can optimize blob upload by making it parallel and asynchronous. You can start your research [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/03/06/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0.aspx).